# Are questions about Coco on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about the 2017 Pixar movie [*Coco*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coco_(2017_film)) on topic?

The film is based on the Mexican holiday the *Day of the Dead*, and has the main character trapped in the spiritual Land of the Dead for most of the film. It contains many fantasy elements, such as deceased ancestors visiting their descendants, [Alebrije](http://Alebrije) guardian spirits, and spirits finding life after death.

Comment: The *Day of the Dead* is based on a combination of Celtic (Samhain/Halloween), Spanish, and Aztec practices, so it should be at least as on-topic as any Halloween movie with ghosts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Yes, this film is absolutely on-topic

---

### Conceit

As you've pointed out, Coco isn't a faithful retelling of a specific religious story (in the manner of [The Passion of the Christ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passion_of_the_Christ))  it's actually a jumbled mish-mash of a variety of different cultures and themes from more than a thousand years of history including some elements that are purely creations of the filmmakers.

Ghosts, magic, spirit-forms and fantastical beasts are all combined into a Mexican-(but also [Mayan](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/features/coco-how-pixar-brought-day-dead-story-life-1065932)- and [Aztec](http://www.chicagotribune.com/hoy/ct-aztec-dog-gains-popularity-in-us-after-coco-20171117-story.html)-)themed extravaganza.

[image]

### Marketing

The film itself is billed by Pixar as containing *magic*

> Despite his family’s baffling generations-old ban on music, Miguel
> (voice of newcomer Anthony Gonzalez) dreams of becoming an
> accomplished musician like his idol, Ernesto de la Cruz (voice of
> Benjamin Bratt). Desperate to prove his talent, Miguel finds himself
> magically transported to the stunning and colorful Land of the Dead
> following a mysterious chain of events. Along the way, he meets
> charming trickster Hector (voice of Gael García Bernal), and together,
> they set off on an extraordinary journey to unlock the real story
> behind Miguel's family history.
>
> <sub><sup>[CHARACTER & TALENT LINEUP REVEALED
> MEET THE EXTENDED FAMILY FROM DISNEY•PIXAR’S “COCO”](http://elteatrocampesino.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/COCO-Character-Talent-Announcement-Press-Release.pdf)</sup></sub>

And that the setting is *fantastical*

> In visualizing the Land of the Dead, Feinberg says the challenge to
> the team was to “make this world something fantastical that no one’s
> ever seen.” The land, inspired in part by the hilly Mexican town of
> Guanajuato located northwest of Mexico City, towers high above the
> ground. It is always nighttime in the Land of Dead, necessitating a
> staggering number of light sources to illuminate a scene that includes
> street lights, lights for the plazas, architectural lighting on bigger
> buildings, blue lights along the trolley tracks, pinlights that
> outline the edges of many buildings, headlights on the moving
> vehicles, lights on the construction cranes and much more.
>
> <sub><sup>[NEWS: Disney•Pixar’s ‘Coco’ Uses Innovative Visual Effects to Celebrate Family and Tradition](http://disneybythenumbers.com/news-disney%E2%80%A2pixars-coco-uses-innovative-visual-effects-celebrate-family-tradition/)</sup></sub>