# Is the show Vikings on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about the Vikings series made by History channel.
This series has some fantasy symptoms (prophets, gods or dead characters that sometimes interact a bit, spectres), but the vast majority of everything that happens there is realistic and possible to happen in the real world (sometimes it even happened in the real world as it is based on the historic events).

My question is: Are questions about Vikings, the series, on topic on SFF SE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No it's not on-topic, but aspects of the show may be.

The show [Vikings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikings_(TV_series)) is marketed on Wikipedia as a *historical drama* not a fantasy. It seems to be quite focused on both historical accuracy and portraying an accurate representation of Vikings. So no, it's not a work of fantasy and is therefore not on-topic.

However, as described in this meta on [non-SF properties with occasional SF-nal elements](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/344/68872) that does not making everything about the show off-topic.

If there are particularly fictional elements of the show that one wants to ask about, they are welcome to. I will however note that prophets and gods are not necessarily fantastical, they very much exist in our world and are believed to be real by a large portion of our populace. Similar to being able to interact with the dead, although they are usually considered fantastical, as are ghosts/spectres (as mention, in passing, [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11625/68872)).

There may be other such elements that are fantastical that one can ask about, but in general no, the show is not on-topic and questions should be redirected to our sister site M&TV.

Comment: Ok. Just to have complete information, are Vikings god believed these days somewhere?

Comment: @TGar As far as I'm aware, no. But the concept of gods is not necessarily Fantastical. Also just to inform you an accept on Meta is effectively pointless, it's whatever has the most votes that count, so I suggest you wait a day or two to collect more answers.

Comment: Yes, that is right of course.

Comment: @TGar - Of course. It's known as Norse Paganism. Some lesser-known white supremacist groups are Norse Pagans (notoriously, Odinism), but not all Norse Pagans are white supremacists.